# File handling in c++ to read two integers

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

How to read two integers from a file which are separated by comma in c++?
For example 
5,6 is written in file how I can read these two integers?

Comment: Do a search on this site for questions with the word "delimiter"

Answer (score -3):

```
    /* sscanf example */
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main ()
    {
      char sentence []="Rudolph is 12 years old";
      char str [20];
      char str2 [20];
      int i;

      sscanf (sentence,"%s %s %d",str,str2,&i);
      //str=Rudolph 
      //str2=is
      //i=12
      printf ("%s %s -> %d\n",str,str2,i);

      return 0;
    }
```

Output: Rudolph is -> 12

```
/* sscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="5,6,7";
  char str [20];
  char str2 [20];
  int i,j,k;

  sscanf (sentence,"%d %*c %d %*c %d",&i,&j,&k);
  printf ("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);

  return 0;
}
```

Output : 5 6 7

Comment: 1) Here we like to not provide code to blatant code requests. 2) This isn't even remotely close to what OP was asking about. 3) This isn't even C++.